# Conflict between Composer autoload and EzPublish one

Tags: php, composer-php, restler, ezpublish

First sorry for my bad English, I'm a French speaker ^^. 
I'm working with Restler as webservice in my eZpublish framework.

When I have installed Restler, I have installed Composer too.

In the index file in witch I use Restler methods, and API classes, I include both ezpublish autoload en restler one, but i have a conflict. When I remove the ezpublish autoload, API classes are not recognized. I want to know how I can, in the composer.json, add all classes of my application.

in the Composer.json file, i have

```
 "autoload":{
        "psr-0":{
            "Luracast\\Restler": "vendor/"
        }
```

` I want to change vendor/ by extension/ because all classes are in extension, Restler classes too. I just want to have all classes with one namespace. Could you help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of eZ Publish are you using? eZ Publish 5 or 4 (Legacy)?

Comment: I'm using the eZpublish 4 version

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using eZ Publish Legacy (4.x), you don't need to add the `autoload` settings for restler in your root composer.json, just add it as a requirement and let composer handle the rest:

```
{
    "require": {
        "luracast/restler": "~3.0"
    }
}
```

In your `index.php` you should then be able to use

```
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

in addition to the eZ Publish autoloads.

For your custom classes inside your extension, you have to execute

```
php bin/php/ezpgenerateautoloads.php -e
```

so that they will be found by the eZ Publish autoloader.

Comment: Yes but when I did that, I have a message error :  Cannot redeclare class Luracast\\Restler\\Format\\JsonFormat in /home/devcnrgv/ezpublish_tko/extension/cnrgv/lib/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Format/JsonFormat.php on line 20 .    In the autoload of eZpublish I have the file JsonFormat.php and when I removed this file, everythig works. I don't know how to correct this problem

Comment: Why is the vendor dir inside your extension dir? If you put the composer.json in the ezpublish root directory, the vendor dir should be in /home/devcnrgv/ezpublish_tko/vendor

Comment: Because the vendor dir was automatically created when I executed composer in the restler dir. And the restler dir is in my extension dir because when it was outside it, all others classes of my application were not detected in the API classes used with restler